# Prevent service from being recreated when activity is destroyed

Tags: android

I have the sticky service that I want to run independently of the app. Right now, the service is recreated every time I close the app by pressing the home key and clearing the app from recent.

I've read that if I started the service in a separate process, it won't be destroyed when I kill the app/activity that started it. But it doesn't seem to be happening. 
This is the service entry in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <service
        android:name="com.example.MyService"
        android:process=":SeparateProcess"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

The service is started with START_STICKY in `onStartCommand()` and is bound to be started on boot completion.

TIA!

Comment: you dont need separate process, how do you use your service in your app?

Comment: It just downloads some data off of a server at regular intervals.

Comment: you use "bound" or "started" service?

Comment: I am using `startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class));`

Comment: in your onDestroy() method of activity call this line stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));

Comment: But I want to keep the service alive even if the app is not in used.

Comment: if you want to talk to your server at regular intervals just use `AlarmManager`

Comment: The requirement specifically states to use a service, actually. So I am bound to using that. Is there a way I can just prevent it from being destroyed when the activity that started it is destroyed?

Comment: use `AlarmManager` + `com.example.MyService`

Comment: As I stated, I cannot add any component to the app. Is there a way to achieve what I want to using services?

Comment: AlarmManager will start your service, this is a normal scenario of doing repetitive tasks

Comment: read this for more info: https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Sure let me go through that..

Comment: @pskink So I tried the AlarmManager but the service would restart as soon as I kill my app. It's behaving the same way.

Comment: so dont use `START_STICKY`

Comment: Wouldn't the service just kill off when an app is killed? I have a broadcast receiver that initiates the alarm manager as described in Developer Docs.

Comment: read service docs: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY